# EkSource class is not supporting in ios 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, ios

i am using EkSource class from  Eventkit framework for creating custum  calender  but  , when i am running application in ios 4.3.3. i am getting following error :-

> 2012-04-03 14:49:36.522 TimeFix[791:707] -[EKEventStore sources]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x252a00 2012-04-03
>   14:49:36.590 TimeFix[791:707] ***
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EKEventStore
>   sources]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x252a00'

but when i am using ios 5.0 ipod for run  application, is working fine with custom calender.
so please suggest me what is the is problem with ios 4.3.3.

Comment: are you calling method that you don't need to call or missing to implement there.

Comment: alternative solution is here https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Comment: it's nice tutorial for calender i love to use it, i have implemented in many application...

Comment: Is there any way to delete all events in iOS 4 calendar without loop?

Comment: sorry i can't get what you want!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows that you might have used something like this

> [EKEventStore sources]

Am I right? If yes,
then apple doc says

> sources
>
> Returns an unordered array of source objects.
>
> - (NSArray *)sources
>
> Return Value An unordered array of EKSource objects.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 5.0 and later. Declared In
> EKEventStore.h

So it is available in iOS 5.0 & later.

Comment: thanks for give me help ,but  what will be the alternative solution for create a custum calender in ios 4.3.3.

Comment: I dont know how exactly you want to customize calendar. But I used [https://github.com/klazuka/Kal] for calendar. see if it helps you.

Comment: Is there any way to delete all events in iOS 4 calendar without loop?

Comment: sorry i dont have any idea about it :(